# Virtualized macOS via UTM will not allow sign in to the App Store for installation of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, mac-appstore, monterey, virtualization

I've installed macOS 12 via [UTM](https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/releases) on an M1 Max, but when I attempt to download Xcode from the App Store with my Apple ID account, it fails to authenticate each time.

Is there a known issue that's blocking the App Store from working in virtualized guests by way of the Apple virtualization technology on Apple Silicon?

Comment: As a side note, Xcode can be installed from developer.apple.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. There is an 'entitlement restriction' which prevents Apple ID related actions in VMs.

Howard Oakley covers it in his series on Virtualisation on Apple Silicon

The Entitlement Restriction refers to the ability of the VM to use bridged or NAT networking. The former requires the entitlement from Apple (which I think applies to the entitlements granted to UTM), and would support Apple ID use, the latter (NAT), while freely available, won't support Apple ID.

See *Networking* in https://eclecticlight.co/2022/07/04/virtualisation-on-apple-silicon-macs-1-how-well-does-it-work/

Though, UTM does allow a switch to bridged networking in a VM's configuration. I haven't tried with a Monterey VM, but feel free.

**Update**

I've tried a Monterey VM in UTM in both shared and bridged network settings. Neither allow the logon with an Apple ID, as you experienced. Maybe as Apple VM, and the applications, mature, it will be feasible. UTM may not have been able to get the entitlements granted. Maybe Apple has something up it's sleeve in Ventura, but now I'm speculating...

Comment: Thanks for giving some clarity and sharing those details. This has been a very frustrating experience thus far and hopefully they either sort it out or other options open up. Sadly top notch virtualization has become more of a necessity today than not and moving to AS/arm64 from x86 has been really felt like a downgrade in several respects.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this issue from a cybersecurity perspective I can not test firewall settings with NewNode VPN to see what it is doing in a sandbox environment. This is what occurs...

A sandbox is just that a tool to use to test items. When use of NewNode occurs it can bypass all firewalls I am told however users that install it do not know it also turns off local services at times. So I am attempting to Sideload the NewNode to test it and block the ports that VPN service is using, again to find it with AppID IPS/IDS I have to use a sandbox....

So again side loading might be the answer to this...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the sideloading tip. Still a bit lost on how to actually do it in a macOS VM - I thought about that for a while, but didn't get anywhere due to some convolution in this field. Any chance you could break down the steps you've taken? If you can't get into some specifics for some various reasons, perhaps you could offer some more direct hints.

Comment: try Github apps, with cmd "git clone" this works great.